# Android constraint layout: resize images for all resolutions

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have placed small image buttons on the one background image. I have managed the positions of small images using constraint layout. But now, the issue is with the size of small image buttons. As screen size changes images are not changing the size.

I have tried with drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi but might be constraint layout is not taking that images. If I apply layout_constraintDimensionRatio, the images change its position for different screens. Or should I use another approach?

[image]

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgMainBg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/bg"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:contentDescription="Background" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnImg1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="btnImg1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/btnImg1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.585"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.183" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnImg2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="btnImg2"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/btnImg2"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.944"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.352" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing with `ConstraintLayout` is that it constraints the views with some guidelines, part of the screen or other sibling views. As the screen sizes grows or shrinks the constraints remain the same. So the relative positioning of the views on the `ConstraintLayout` do change based on screen sizes. If you are using png or other images in your drawable folder, you can provide different images in the `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-ldpi` and other folders. The images should have different sizes for you to be able to see the images grow and shrink as the app is tested on different `dpi` screens.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Yes I am using all png images. if I place images in drawable-hdpi , drawable-ldpi and other folders then it is advisable to remove app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent",   app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" , app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" , app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent". if I remove these, images can't stick to original position for different screen size. Also should I keep height and width as wrap_content?

Comment: I don't think you need to remove those constraints at all. You can have all the constraints you want. I believe you are trying to achieve resizing, you should use `wrap_content` for both `height` and `width`.

Comment: Also if you use the set of constraints and `height` and `width`, there is some chance that images might be truncated at some parts on some screens because a high dpi screen does not necessarily mean it is a large screen phone. In that case you will have to provide separate `layout` folder for `available-width` or `smallest-width` qualifiers. More about these resources [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources)